# Setting mailto using javascript leads to unpredictable results

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailto

I have a form with `id` `email_form` and a blank action:

```
<form id="email_form" action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="set_form_action()">
```

This is the definition of the function `set_form_action()`:

```
function set_form_action() {
   document.getElementById("email_form").action = 
   'mailto:helloworld@helloworld.com' + 
   '?subject=Test email&body=Thank you for your order.' +
   ' Please see below for your order details.' +
   '%0D%0A%0D%0A----------------------%0D%0A' +
   'Name: ' + document.getElementById("name").value + '%0D%0A' +
   'Date: ' + document.getElementById("date").value + '%0D%0A' +
   // etc...
}
```

The result is unpredictable. On Linux Firefox, everything works properly. The body is filled in correctly and the "To:" field is correctly set to `helloworld@helloworld.com` as well.

However, running the same HTML page on Linux Chrome, the "To:" field is set to `///helloworld@helloworld.com`. Also, this page does not work at all on Windows Firefox or Chrome, the body and To: fields are both completely empty.

How is the `mailto` function defined and what determines how the data is parsed and sent to the email client?

Comment: you would be much better off dealing with this sort of thing server-side

Comment: @georg yes, but my question wasn't related to which technology I should use to get the task done most effectively, mostly because those types of questions are considered not good questions, but also because that isn't the answer I'm looking for at all. I am curious how `action="mailto:..."` _actually works_ in the browser and why there are so many weird results using different browsers. It should be possible to figure this out because all browsers are open source, but I'm not sure where to start, which is why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

Just tested the following code:

```html
<form name="email_form" action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

</form>

<button onclick="set_form_action()">Set Form Action</button>

<script>
function set_form_action() {
   document.email_form.action = 
   'mailto:helloworld@helloworld.com';
   alert(document.email_form.action);
}
</script>
```

And it works just fine in the following browsers:

- Latest Firefox Version 58.0.2
- Latest Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.18920
- Safari Version 11.0.3

I don't have Linux, so can't test on there. I really can't see why you are having an issue. But I hope this helps to start getting you pointed in the right direction.